# Custom Taxonomy Terms in Menu lead to which page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

Hello All I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have created a custom post type along with a custom taxonomy. In this custom taxonomy I have created custom terms through the wp dashboard. I have added these terms to my Nav menu when I click on these terms in goes to a page. My question here is is that page the archive.php? How would I style that page how I want? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the template taxonomy.php, and some variants: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: if i create a taxonmy-producttype.php (producttype) being my custom taxonomy. Will this apply to all terms under this taxonomy? or would I have to make a page for each term under the taxonomy? I would rather have it so if i decide to add more terms under this taxonomy it automatically formats them all the same for each term

Comment: It will apply to all terms of that taxonomy. You can specify additional templates for specific terms using the taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php template; e.g. all term pages could use taxonomy-cars.php, except for ones specified like taxonomy-cars-honda.php and taxonomy-cars-bmw.php.

Comment: I have created a taxonomy-producttype.php But when I click on the terms in the nav menu it does not go to the taxonomy-producttype.php any idea why?

Comment: It's a little hard to day w/o seeing anything. got any code?

Comment: I did it, i forgot to go into the permalinks and re save it in order for the template to recognize thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The page for any particular term should definitely be an archive page.

Check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and you will see that wordpress looks for the following templates to display terms

- taxonomy-(taxonomy)-(term).php
- taxonomy-(taxonomy).php
- taxonomy.php
- archive.php
- paged.php (maybe)
- index.php

So if you want to create a custom layout, copy your archive.php (if it exists) and give it the name taxonomy-(your_taxonomy_name).php and then have at it and that should only apply to terms for your custom taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you Tarackus and Privateer for your responses I think you both are saying the same thing. @Privateer if i create taxonomy-(customTaxonomy).php will this layout apply to all my terms.

Comment: Yes. as long as (customTaxonomy) in your statement is the name of your custom taxonomy.